# Git replay changes on new directory of updated initial files

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch, rebase

I've got a repo that I started with an initial commit of a ton of files and then made A LOT of changes. After some time (now), I want to apply the same commits to an updated verison of the same starting files. What's the best way to do this? There seem to be a lot of options - git diff, git format-patch, git filter-branch, and on and on. I've tried a few, but seem to get a lot of errors.

I've squashed it down to two commits - "Initial Import" and "Changes".  I think what I'd like to do is start a new repo with a new "Initial import" (of the updated base files) and then cherry-pick the "Changes" commit on top. Then, I can set upstream to the original and push -f.  This does not work, however.

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Instead of an all-new repo, start with a new branch and rebase "changes" onto it.

Comment: You don't need to squash anything to do a rebase.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Mad Physicist.  That worked.  I added a "choose theirs" strategy to the rebase too just to make things a little smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a new branch
2. Delete everything in it
3. Copy the new initial files in
4. Cherry-pick the "contents" commit in:

   `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs <"contents"-commit-hash>`